# How to deal with Warning C4100 in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio

For some reason my Visual Studio 2008 began to show warnings for code like: 
"int main( int argc, char **argv)", which is really annoying.

The detailed warning ouputs are (you can ignore the line numbers):
1>.\main.cpp(86) : warning C4100: 'argv' : unreferenced formal parameter
1>.\main.cpp(86) : warning C4100: 'argc' : unreferenced formal parameter

I wonder if there are settings in Visual Studio 2008 that have been accidentally changed. Or how should I deal with this warning?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If the parameters are unreferenced, you can leave them unnamed:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
}
```

instead of

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
}
```

If you really want just to suppress the warning, you can do so using the `/wd4100` command line option to the compiler or using `#pragma warning(disable: 4100)` in your code.

This is a level 4 warning; if you compile at a lower warning level, you won't get this warning.  The warning level is set in the project properties (right-click project, select Properties; on the Configuration Properties -> C++ -> General, set "Warning Level").

Comment: Is there any setting in VS2008 that I can play with? Because for codes I wrote earlier, this C4100 warning does show up with I compile them.Thank you.

Comment: @Jimmie:  Yes; you can change the warning level for your project to some lower warning level (e.g., level 3).

Comment: Note that having unnamed parameters in the function definition is OK in C++, but if your compiling as C it's an error (a small irritation sometimes when trying to write code that compiles either way).

Answer (score 5):

Warning C4100 is issued at warning level 4 which is not default, so at some point someone probably changed it for your project.

You could change the warning level back, or address the warning more directly.

As [James McNellis said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519851/how-to-deal-with-warning-c4100-in-visual-studio-2008/2519862#2519862), you can silence the warning in C++ by removing the parameter name from the parameter list. However, if the code will be compiled as C code you'll get an error in that case.

The Windows headers define the macro `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER()` to help deal with this warning.  You could use

```
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( argc);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER( argv);
```

to silence the warning. If you don't want to include windows headers, the macro simply expands to a use of the parameter name in a do nothing expression:

```
#define UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(P)          \
    /*lint -save -e527 -e530 */ \
    { \
        (P) = (P); \
    } \
    /*lint -restore */
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER`; that's good to know.  In the Windows headers, there are two versions.  The one enabled by default simply expands to `(P)`.  The other one, which you quote, expands to `(P) = (P);`, and is used if `lint` is defined; this one will fail for parameters of const-qualified or nonassignable types.

Comment: @James - the more 'complicated' definition is just what my ctags jump happened to land on (I should have scrolled up a bit - especially since I was a bit surprised that the expansion wasn't just `(P)`).

Answer (score 5):

If you're not using the command line parameters then the other standard signature for main is:

```
int main();
```

Comment: The other standard signature has a void between those brackets, does it not?

Comment: Yes, in C; no difference in C++ because they're equivalent. Question was tagged C++, so I went with the form of no params that I usually use in C++.